# How to backup minecraft worlds in a batch from the OS?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-spigot

*I am not sure this is the right SE for this question, another place could be the [Game Development SE](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) - feel free to move it if appropriate.*

I run a `spigot` (`minecraft`) server for my children and would like to back up their worlds (they use Multiverse). Is there a right way to do that from the OS level **without stopping the server**?

Note: I am specifically asking about the restrictions on `spigot` side - how to perform the backup on the OS is something simple I will take care of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, I either use plugins like the following:

[Simple Backup - Bukkit](https://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/simplebackup/)

These plugins will make sure the world is flushed to disk and then copied over to a backup folder. You cannot just copy over the world at random times because you might be copying partial worlds over.

---

If you don't want to use plugins, you could also pass the following commands to stdin:

```
/save-off
/save-all
```

then you should wait for a while, something like 30 seconds should be enough. Then you could copy the world and other files that need backing up.

Then, after that it is a good idea to pass the following command into stdin:

```
/save-on
```

This method basically turns off autosave, then forces a flush. Then you can copy the file, and when you are done, you re-enable autosave.

Comment: Thanks, I will try the plugin-based solution first. For those who run the server under screen or tmux, it is possible to [send key stokes in batch mode](http://serverfault.com/a/547144/78319)

Comment: Forgot to put in the answer, if you have a dedicated box, mineos is worth looking into.

Comment: This is very interesting, thank you. I use a virtual server under `systemd-nspawn` so the step-by-step information are very useful. I will contribute back with info for `systemd` based systems.

Comment: This one seems interesting: https://github.com/Ahtenus/minecraft-init

Comment: I have a running virtual container which auto-starts `tmux` running minecraft so the init part is not a problem. The other functionalities in the mineos you pointed at are very interesting, though - specifically the web frontend.